# How to concatenate literal strings with numerical macro?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to make a literal string by merging a non string macro as follow?

```cpp
#define SOC 12

printf("This is the default SoC:" SOC "!");
```

[UPDATE]

This is embedded cpp 11 and I'd like to limit resource usage so I need a compile-time solution, not runtime.

Comment: Convert the integer into a string and then concatenate the strings together.  That said, using C++ like the Q is tagged gives you `std::cout << "text" << number << "more text";`

Comment: This is embedded cpp 11 and I'd like to limit resource usage

Comment: If you're using C++, you should avoid `printf` and instead use `std::string`s with `std::cout`

Comment: And then you wouldn't need to concatenate the strings. If you really need to concat strings, use `std::to_string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With preprocessor, you might stringify the value:

```
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define STRINGIFY_VALUE(s) STRINGIFY(s)
```

and then use concatenation of C-strings:

```
printf("This is the default SoC:" STRINGIFY_VALUE(SOC) "!");
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jW3sffhsa)